# Punctuation and Near Query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

When I turned on `punctuation-insensitive` in my `cts:word-query`, even then the `NEAR` query is breaking the `-` word into two words

```
let $xml :=

  <abstracts count="1">
            <abstract>
              <abstract_text count="1">
                <p>We assessed the impact of a pharmacotherapy follow-up programme on key safety points [adverse events (AE) 
                and drug administration] in outpatients treated with oral antineoplastic agents (OAA). We performed a comparative, 
                interventional, quasi-experimental study of outpatients treated with OAA in a Spanish hospital to compare pre-intervention 
                group patients (not monitored by pharmacists during 2011) with intervention group patients (prospectively monitored by 
                pharmacists during 2013). AE data were collected from medical records. Follow-up was 6 months, and 249 patients were 
                included (pre-intervention, 115; intervention, 134). After the first month, AE were detected in 86.5% of patients 
                in the pre-intervention group and 80.6% of patients in the intervention group, P = 0.096. During the remaining months, 
                79.0% patients had at least one AE in the pre-intervention group compared with 78.0% in the intervention group, P = 0.431. 
                AE were more prevalent with sorafenib and sunitinib. In total, 173 drug interactions were recorded (pre-intervention, 80; 
                intervention, 93; P = 0.045). Drug interactions were more frequent with erlotinib and gefitinib; food interactions were 
                more common with sorafenib and pazopanib. Our follow-up of cancer outpatients revealed a reduction in severe AE and major 
                drug interactions, thus helping health professionals to monitor the safety of OAA.</p>
              </abstract_text>
            </abstract>
          </abstracts>

let $q3 :=
    cts:near-query(
      (
       cts:element-query((xs:QName("abstract_text")),
          cts:word-query( ("Controlled", "randomized", "randomised", "clinical", "masked","blind*","multi center", "open label*","compar*", "cross over", "placebo",
                "post market","meta analysis","volunteer*", "prospective"
                ),
          ("case-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "wildcarded"))
        )
        ,
        cts:element-query((xs:QName("abstract_text")),
          cts:word-query(("stud*", "trial*" ),
          ("case-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "wildcarded"))
        )
      ),   
       3
    )

return 
  cts:highlight($xml,$q3, <b>{$cts:text}</b>)
```

When I put the `NEAR` to `3` then it does not match `comparative` and `study` even though the distance is `3` and I have it `punctuation-insensitive`. But when I change it to `4` it works..

But when I also change to `punctuation-sensitive` even then with  `NEAR` distance to `3` still does not match . Why is that ?

And also I want to achieve in the `word-query` to match say `placebo-controlled` and `placebo controlled`. which I think once I turn on the `punctuation-insensitive` and search for `placebo controlled` in my word query will find all combinations of the words.. But how will this effect the `NEAR` distance, when the same is used in the `NEAR` query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing do with punctuation in resolving your search but rather how MarkLogic tokenizes and indexes the position of individual words. By default, MarkLogic's tokenization breaks hyphenated phrases into separate words. You can use a custom tokenizer to dictate how MarkLogic should index words if you don't like the default behavior. There is a pretty detailed guide on using a custom tokenizer to ignore hyphens in word tokenization [available here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-tokenization).

For your case, I'm not sure I would recommend you explore using a custom tokenizer. There can be unintended consequences and it's not as performant as using the default tokenization. Instead, it would probably make more sense to adapt your code to how the default tokenization works.

Let's look at : `comparative, interventional, quasi-experimental study`

It would be tokenized like :

```
Word            | Position
comparative     | 0
interventional  | 1
quasi           | 2
experimental    | 3
study           | 4
```

Thus, the distance between `comparative` and `study` is 4. Note that `quasi-experimental` is tokenized into two words.

I'm not sure I understood the question you are asking in your last paragraph. But I hope this gives you enough information to better understand how the default tokenization behaves.

Comment: You can run something like this to see the tokenization in action: cts:tokenize ('comparative, interventional, quasi-experimental study') ! xdmp:describe (.)